# In an ordered field, if all rational Cauchy sequences converge, must all Cauchy sequences converge?

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

In other words, does there exist an ordered field in which all rational Cauchy sequences converge, but some Cauchy sequences do not converge?

Comment: What do you mean by "rational Cauchy sequence"?  A sequence of rationals that is Cauchy in the usual sense (i.e., as a sequence in $\mathbb{Q}$)?  Or a sequence of rationals that is Cauchy in your ordered field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be an ordered field. Then $\mathbb Q$ is a subfield of $F.$

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of members of $\mathbb Q.$ We will call it a Cauchy sequence in $F$ if there is some $\ell\in F$ such that for every positive $\varepsilon\in F,$ all but finitely many $a_n$ are between $\ell\pm\varepsilon.$

Either $F$ is a subfield of $\mathbb R$ or it has some members not in $\mathbb R.$

So we suppose $F$ is not a subfield of $\mathbb R.$ Should I leave it as an exercise to show that in that case $F$ contains some positive members $\iota$ that are smaller than any member of $\mathbb Q\text{?}$ In that case, can any Cauchy sequence in $F$ whose terms are rational converge to $\iota\text{?}$ No rational number is between $\iota\pm\iota/2,$ so it can't happen.

Therefore, the only ordered field in which every Cauchy sequence of rationals converges is $\mathbb R.$